# Ruby: unexplained behaviour of String#sub in the presence of "\\'"

Tags: ruby

I can't understand why this happens:

```
irb(main):015:0> s = "Hello\\'World"
=> "Hello\\'World"
irb(main):016:0> "#X#".sub("X",s)
=> "#Hello#World#"
```

I would have thought the output would be "#Hello\'World#", and I certainly can't understand where the extra # came from.

I guess I'm unfamiliar with something that has got to do with the internals of String#sub and to the "\'" symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's due to the use of backslash in a `sub` replacement string.

Your replacement string contains `\'` which is expanded to the global variable `$'` which is [otherwise known as](http://www.rubyinside.com/advent2006/11-english.html) `POSTMATCH`. For a string replacement, it contains everything in the string which exists following the matched text. So because your `X` that you replaced is followed by a `#`, that's what gets inserted.

Compare:

```
"#X$".sub("X",s)
=> "#Hello$World$"
```

Note that the documentation for [`sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-sub) refers to use of backreferences `\0` through `\9`. This seems to refer directly to the global variables `$0` to `$9` and also applies to other global variables.

For reference, the [other global variables](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#label-Special+global+variables) set by regular expression matching are:

```
$~ is equivalent to ::last_match;

$& contains the complete matched text;

$` contains string before match;

$' contains string after match;

$1, $2 and so on contain text matching first, second, etc capture group;

$+ contains last capture group.
```

Comment: I didn't understand what happened.. Would you please tell me the story of `$'` ? Why the same has not been happened with the block form ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit - Check out the links in my answer, but basically, when you match a regular expression Ruby sets some global variables. One of them is `$'`

Comment: @Gareth Ok..but we didn't use any RegEx here,only a string.. Then how? Why not with block form?

Comment: "If replacement is a String it will be substituted for the matched text. It may contain back-references to the pattern’s capture groups of the form "\d", where d is a group number, or "\k<n>", where n is a group name. If it is a double-quoted string, both back-references must be preceded by an additional backslash. However, within replacement the special match variables, such as &$, will not refer to the current match."

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-sub